# PayPal Recurring Billing - Is there a way to use a trial period and still bill a person at the same time

Tags: c#, paypal, recurring-billing

Here is the scenario: Let's say a person signs up to be a paying member of my site.  Now let's say the same member could sign up for classes internal to the application but require recurring billing scenarios as well.  We would like to use the same billing profile and just say in 60 days.  For example, if someone sign up for $5 per month, then signs up for one of the classes at $30 p/month with a 60 day trial.  The person should be billed using their billing profile created when they signed up for the $5 amount, for $5 per month until the trial period end then $35 per month after the period end.  Is there a way to both bill someone and have a trial period running on the same profile?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you basically want:

1. First month - $5 / month
2. After that $35 / month indefinitely

If this is correct you basically need to utilize both a1, t1, p1 and a2, t2, p2 variables in this fashion:

- a1=5, t1=1, p1=M
- a2=35, t2=1, p2=M

Of course you need to setup src=1 (yes to recurring payments) and srt=0 (repeat indefinitely).

You can see details on [HTML Variables for Recurring Payments Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU).

Comment: Would it matter if I am using PayFlowPro?